# Help Identifying a capacitor WITHOUT a capacitance meter and no markings?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, identification, capacitance

I have a DELL 2408WFP Monitor purchased in 2009 that I am currently using right now. I have an issue with that monitor where it runs hot and shuts off after a certain period of time. This could be due to a number of issues but with limited testing equipment, I'm planning on taking a shotgun approach to solving the issue. I suspect this could be due to dying/aging capacitors on the power supply board and would like to swap them out sine a few look suspect. All the heat seams to be coming from the power supply board and if it gets hot enough the monitor shuts off but the power light stays on.

I know this could also be the inverter board but since it seams so heat dependent and since all the heat seems to come from the PSU I'm going to start there. Also putting a fan behind the monitor keeps it alive for hours on end without issue. Without the fan, it powers off after about two hours of use (and I mean box fan type fan).

I have identified all capacitors on the Power Supply Unit except for one that does not have a visible farad rating because it is glued down to the board.

Can anyone help to identify this capacitor? Also any tips on removing that silicone glue?

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the full board:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I know I have the power pin disconnected in that last picture. The inverter is on the left and PSU on top. I am guessing that unidentified capacitor is 450V based on the cut-off marking on the bottom. I'm not sure what the "5A" marking is. Appears to be rated for 105degC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Service manual says it's 150 uF 450 V in the first schematic pages. Later on it is said to be 120uF.

If the silicone is soft, a hobby knife or equivalent should be able to cut it.

Comment: Hey where did you get that service manual? Sounds like that's just the ticket I would need.

Comment: I put "dell 2408wfp service manual" into my favourite search engine and a few seconds later it opens. So most likely it took more time to write that question than to find the service manual.